# How to find the nearest neighbour index from one series to another

Tags: python, python-3.x, vectorization, knn, nearest-neighbor

I have a target array A, which represents isobaric pressure levels in NCEP reanalysis data.
I also have the pressure at which a cloud is observed as a long time series, B.

What I am looking for is a k-nearest neighbour lookup that returns the indices of those nearest neighbours, something like `knnsearch` in Matlab that could be represented the same in python such as: `indices, distance = knnsearch(A, B, n)`
where `indices` is the nearest `n` indices in `A` for every value in `B`, and `distance` is how far removed the value in `B` is from the nearest value in `A`, and `A` and `B` can be of different lengths (this is the bottleneck that I have found with most solutions so far, whereby I would have to loop each value in `B` to return my `indices` and `distance`)

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([1000, 925, 850, 700, 600, 500, 400, 300, 250, 200, 150, 100, 70, 50, 30, 20, 10]) # this is a fixed 17-by-1 array
B = np.array([923, 584.2, 605.3, 153.2]) # this can be any n-by-1 array
n = 2
```

What I would like returned  from `indices, distance = knnsearch(A, B, n)` is this:

```
indices = [[1, 2],[4, 5] etc...]
```

where `923` in `A` is matched to first `A[1]=925` and then `A[2]=850`
and `584.2` in `A` is matched to first `A[4]=600` and then `A[5]=500`

```
distance = [[72, 77],[15.8, 84.2] etc...]
```

where `72` represents the distance between queried value in `B` to the nearest value in `A` e.g. `distance[0, 0] == np.abs(B[0] - A[1])`

The only solution I have been able to come up with is:

```
import numpy as np


def knnsearch(A, B, n):
    indices = np.zeros((len(B), n))
    distances = np.zeros((len(B), n))

    for i in range(len(B)):
        a = A
        for N in range(n):
            dif = np.abs(a - B[i])
            ind = np.argmin(dif)

            indices[i, N] = ind + N
            distances[i, N] = dif[ind + N]
            # remove this neighbour from from future consideration
            np.delete(a, ind)

    return indices, distances


array_A = np.array([1000, 925, 850, 700, 600, 500, 400, 300, 250, 200, 150, 100, 70, 50, 30, 20, 10])
array_B = np.array([923, 584.2, 605.3, 153.2])
neighbours = 2

indices, distances = knnsearch(array_A, array_B, neighbours)

print(indices)
print(distances)
```

returns:

```
[[ 1.  2.]
 [ 4.  5.]
 [ 4.  3.]
 [10. 11.]]

[[  2.   73. ]
 [ 15.8  84.2]
 [  5.3  94.7]
 [  3.2  53.2]]
```

There must be a way to remove the for loops, as I need the performance should my A and B arrays contain many thousands of elements with many nearest neighbours...

Please help! Thanks :)

Comment: Is it expected behaviour that the nearest neighbours of 605.3 are 600 and 500 instead of 600 and 700?

Comment: @xg.plt.py Ah! no. That's my bad. I sort of half solved my original question whilst formulating the question. Those outputs were manually entered and subjected to my errors.... I will edit to fix. Nice spot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second loop can easily be vectorized. The most straightforward way to do it is to use `np.argsort` and select the indices corresponding to the n smallest `dif` values. However, for large arrays, as only n values should be sorted, it is better to use [`np.argpartition`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html).

Therefore, the code would look like something like that:

```
def vector_knnsearch(A, B, n):
    indices = np.empty((len(B), n))
    distances = np.empty((len(B), n))

    for i,b in enumerate(B):
        dif = np.abs(A - b)
        min_ind = np.argpartition(dif,n)[:n] # Returns the indexes of the 3 smallest
                                             # numbers but not necessarily sorted
        ind = min_ind[np.argsort(dif[min_ind])] # sort output of argpartition just in case
        indices[i, :] = ind
        distances[i, :] = dif[ind]

    return indices, distances
```

As said in the comments, the first loop can also be removed using a meshgrid, however, the extra use of memory and computation time to construct the meshgrid makes this approach slower for the dimensions I tried (and this will probably get worse for large arrays and end up in Memory Error). In addition, the readability of the code decreases. Overall, this would probably do this approach less pythonic.

```
def mesh_knnsearch(A, B, n):
    m = len(B)
    rng = np.arange(m).reshape((m,1))
    Amesh, Bmesh = np.meshgrid(A,B)
    dif = np.abs(Amesh-Bmesh)
    min_ind = np.argpartition(dif,n,axis=1)[:,:n]
    ind = min_ind[rng,np.argsort(dif[rng,min_ind],axis=1)]

    return ind, dif[rng,ind]
```

Not that it is important to define this `rng` as a 2d array in order to retrieve `a[rng[0],ind[0]]`, `a[rng[1],ind[1]]`, etc and maintain the dimensions of the array, as opposed to `a[:,ind]` which retrieves `a[:,ind[0]]`, `a[:,ind[1]]`, etc.

Comment: This is nice. Thanks for the hint @xg.plt.py

I have a question relating to the need such a manually specified knnsearch.
I am using xarray and have been using the `mode="nearest"' for the `.sel` functionality of the data array. It strikes me that it is the same process behind the scenes as it takes a similar amount of time to return the result between me specifying the `indices` into `.isel`, or letting xarray do its thing with the `nearest` mode in `isel`... CONTD

Comment: .......contiuned
One solution I would find for my vectorisation problem in matlab would be to create a meshgrid of `A` and `B` so that I would have a single vector with all combinations of `A[i]` and `B[i]`. Then this would remove the `for i,b in enumerate(B)`, though increase memory of the new meshed variable by `A*len(B)`.

Is there pythonic way to implement this idea?

Thanks for your time :)